# Unable to call a function stored as string from inside a class

Tags: php, event-handling, singleton

**EDIT: Sorry guys, it was a typo =(**

I feel embarrassed for wasting your time on this. I'm leaving this thread open in hopes that someone might find the discussed information useful.

*To clarify further, the code below will work as expected, I mistyped 'classHandler' in my code, and that's the reason PHP couldn't find it.*

*Also, the syntax errors noted by some commenters have been corrected*

I feel obligated to summarize the discussion on this thread:

---

@wimvds suggests using inheritance and that my implementation is not a good practice.

@Victor Nicollet disagrees saying extending the behavior of an existing instance is 1. impossible and 2. bad design

@ircmaxell adds: Remember, you should always favor composition over inheritance. And this isn't spaghetti code, it's a pretty standard method of implementing a stripped down notification system (You could build a full blown observer or mediator pattern, but for really simple tasks, this may be a whole lot better since it's easier to maintain).

@Victor asks for a minimal one file example returning this error. This is what helped me solve the issue. When I tried the sample file, it work perfectly leading me to believe that something else indeed was wrong.

@Shakti Singh suggests trying `call_user_func( array( $this, $this->handler ), $var);`

@Victor Nicollet responds saying This would attempt to call a member function $this->classHandler (which probably doesn't exist) instead of the global classHandler

@abesto gives it a shot, ends up with a very similar implementation as my own, which works without my typo.

@Victor Nicollet answers by claiming that the classHandler needs to be defined prior to the call.

@Blizz responds by saying that PHP parses classes and functions first and then the regular code.

---

**MyClass.php** ( singleton )

```
public $handler;

public function myMethod()
{
    $var = "test";
    call_user_func( $this->handler, $var ); 
    // PHP Warning: First argument is expected to be a valid callback
}
```

**Script.php**

```
$myClass = new MyClass;
$myClass->handler = "classHandler";
$myClass->myMethod();

function classHandler( $var )
{
    echo $var;
}
```

If this is incorrect, what is the commonly practiced means of invoking handlers / event handlers in php?

*Note that this is a simplified version of the actual script*

Comment: there are a lot of syntax errors in the script. A new class instance is made by `$myClass = new MyClass` for example

Comment: This should work just fine as long as `classHandler` is a regular function and not a class method.  Syntax issues aside, what are your exact errors/who isn't it working?

Comment: Ok, but the question you should ask yourself first is : why are you not overriding your myMethod function - or use a relevant pattern on your OO code? Because now you're creating spaghetti code that will take ages to understand/debug for someone who didn't write it...

Comment: @wimvds: because using inheritance to extend the behavior of an existing instance is 1. impossible and 2. bad design ;-)

Comment: @powtac: That was something i missed out when writing the question, the class is instantiated correctly in my code. @ircmaxell, `classHandler` is a regular function outside the class in Script.php. I'm getting a warning that says `First argument is expected to be a valid callback`.

Comment: Given that the most obvious errors are not present, could you 1° `var_dump($this->handler)` and 2° try to provide a complete one-file minimal example that exhibits the behavior you are seeing?

Comment: @gAMB: try adding a `var_dump($this->handler)` in `myMethod` and see what's in there and is throwing the error...  @wimvds: because doing that via inheritance would break encapsulation and the single responsibility principle.  Remember, you should always favor composition over inheritance.  And this isn't spaghetti code, it's a pretty standard method of implementing a stripped down notification system (You could build a full blown observer or mediator pattern, but for really simple tasks, this may be a whole lot better since it's easier to maintain)...

Comment: `var_dump( $this->handler );` just before the call gives me the string 'classHandler', so it's being passed correctly.

Comment: @gAMB: could you post more code?  That should work just fine (and it does on my system).  Something else must be going on...

Comment: @gAMB: After reading your edit, either post an answer as to what the problem was and how you fixed it (so others can benefit from the solution), or delete the question (if it doesn't provide others help).  But glad to see it's working!

Answer (score 2):

You have to call something like this

```
call_user_func( array( $this, $this->handler ), $var);
```

Comment: This would attempt to call a member function `$this->classHandler` (which probably doesn't exist) instead of the global `classHandler` function defined in `Script.php`.

Comment: @Victor: Yes, You are right The method must be the public member of class for this answer

Answer (score 0):

Read your `Script.php` code again. What it's doing is:

1. Instantiate `MyClass` (I'm assuming you forgot the `new` here).
2. Define the handler to be `classHandler`.
3. Run `myMethod()`, which attempts to call `classHandler`.
4. Define `classHandler`.

Obviously, if you run 3 before you run 4, it's not going to work. You must define the function first, and *then* run any code that might want to call it.

In the larger scheme of things, I suspect there is no file like `Script.php`, and instead file **A** defines the class, file **B** instantiates the class and runs `myMethod`and file **C** defines `classHandler`. In such a situation, you need to make sure that file **C** is loaded before **B** is run.

Comment: Actually that's not true. PHP parses classes and functions first and then the regular code. - Edit: To be clear, I'm talking about within the same file here :)

Comment: @Blizz : true (if within the same file).

Comment: @Blizz: that's assuming that the class/function is not conditionally defined (inside of another construct such as an if or another function).

Comment: I defined the `classHandler` before the call to `myMethod`, and there was no difference. I'm still getting the warning. Also, there is a `Script.php` which defines and instantiates `myClass`, and also calls `myMethod`. The handler is defined in the same script.

Comment: @ircmaxell: It's defined directly under Script.php.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: if by storing functions as strings you mean that the actual implementation is in the string, then this is bad practice. You don't have to do it to get what you want.

```
function afun($param) {}
class BClass { function bfun($param) {} }

call_user_func('afun', 'param');  // Calls function afun

$binstance = new BClass();
call_user_func(array($binstance, 'bfun'), 'param'); // Calls bfun on binstance 


// Update according to comment
class CClass {
    private $handler;

    public function __construct($handler) { $this->handler = $handler; }

    public foo() {
      // do stuff
      call_user_func($this->handler, 'param');
    }
}
$cinstance = new CClass('afun');
$cinstance->foo();
```

Comment: You're calling bFun of BClass and global function afun in the top-level script. What I'm trying to do is to call afun from within BClass, and have afun passed to BClass as parameter.

Comment: The answer wasn't a direct solution, but I realize that my update is practically the same as what you wrote in the question. Still, maybe it'll be useful.

Comment: Since you thought out the implementation and it came very close to my own, the fact reinforces my belief that I am at least in the right direction =D